# Is it legal to use the web-root as the root of a WCF-RESTservice

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

Is it legal to create a RESTful WCF service within an asp.net website, where a ServiceRoute  directly points to the root of the web.
I have tested it with the VS2010 integrated webserver and it worked exactly as I desire, but is this a hack and may I encounter problems with such a combination in production environment?

To elaborate: I have some .aspx-pages in the website, the webs root is also defined with a default.aspx website. Additionaly, I want to integrated some REST-resources through the WCF web-service within this website and I want that the URIs are in the range of the websites URIs.

Example:
http://[server]/ -> Here the default.aspx should be executed
http://[server]/APage.aspx -> Here the APage.aspx should be executed
http://[server]/Users/[UserName]/ -> Here a service method declared with [WebGet] should be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The described design seems to work on production IIS, although there must be done additional configuration (in any way, not only to set the root. See the code-block below).

However after doing this, all unknown requests will be routed to the web service. When a client calls the path to the website without a page, such as `http://[server]` or `http://[server]/News` and no REST-Resource has assignet to this path, the WCF-help will be displayed (if enabled).

To enable a combination of asp.net and a wcf-REST-Service, set the `multipleSiteBindingsEnabled`-attribute of the `serviceHostingEnvironment`-element to `true`.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
      ...
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```